# null checking in kendo grid numeric filter?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a numeric field in kendo grid and that field is null-able. so I am using a kendo template and showing "N/A" when value is null. How to filter that column for null fields?, I cant type "null" which is the actual data in the data source, because filter is a numeric text box. Let me know how to handle this scenario?

to enable filtering, using  `filterable: true,` in Grid

to show 4 decimals in filter text box, using columns.filterable property

```
 filterable: {
                            ui: function (element) {
                                element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                                    format: "n19",
                                    decimals: 4
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

UPDATE: I am using client side filtering.

Comment: you can replace null values to empty string in your dataset...

Comment: what type of front end filtering you are doing...server or client ???